# How to save imageview as bitmap automatically once layout loads in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a button that saves the imageview as a bitmap once clicked but I need to save a temp version of the imageview as a bitmap once the layout has finished loading and the imageview's drawing cache has been built. I tried to call my save imageview method in the onPostCreate method but it returned a null pointer exception in regards to the imageview cache. How can I automatically save the imageview once the activity has finished loading?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your queshion right. You can try to extend your custom RelativeLayout and override method onDraw in it. This method calls when canvas was drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by loading the imageview using an AsyncTask class that renders the image, builds cache in the preExecute method then saves the imageview in the postExecute method.